# How can I test linearity (superposition) & shift-invariance in Python?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm new to Python & writing a program that takes a function:

```
X = np.linspace(0,50)
F1 = np.sin(X)
```

Tests whether the function is linear (as in, exhibits superposition):

```
for i in range(1,10):
  LT1 = i*(F1)
  X = i*X
  LT2 = F1
  if np.all(LT1) == np.all(LT2):
    Linear = 'This function is linear.'
  elif np.all(LT1) != np.all(LT2):
    Linear = 'This function is nonlinear.'
    break
```

And tests whether the function is shift-invariant:

```
for j in range(1,10):
  SI1 = (F1)-j
  X = X-j
  SI2 = F1
  if np.all(SI1) == np.all(SI2):
    SI = 'This function is shift-invariant.'
  elif np.all(SI1) != np.all(SI2):
    SI = 'This function is shift-variant.'
    break
```

But my code calls all functions, LSI or not, linear & shift-variant. Is there a better way to run these tests? I've seen linear regression offered as a means of testing linearity, but upon trying it with a sine function it misclassified the function as nonlinear. I have also been unable to find any guidance whatsoever on testing shift-invariance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets first define all the required functionality

```
import numpy as np

def check_linearity(T, X, a, b):
  # T[a*x+b*x] = a*T[x] + b*T[x]
  LHS = T(a*x + b*x)
  RHS = a*T(x) + b*T(x)
  tolerence = 1e-4
  if np.sum(LHS-RHS) < tolerence:
    print('Linear System')
    return True
  else:
    print('Not a Linear System')
    return False

def check_shift_invariance(T, X, tau):
  # T[X] = T[X-tau]
  LHS = T(X)
  RHS = T(X-tau)
  tolerence = 1e-4
  if np.sum(LHS-RHS) < tolerence:
    print('Shift Invariant System')
    return True
  else:
    print('Not a Shift Invariant System')
    return False

def check_LSI(T, X, a, b, tau):
  flag1 = check_linearity(T, X, a, b)
  flag2 = check_shift_invariance(T, X, tau)
  if flag1== True and flag2==True:
    print('LSI system')
  else:
    print('not a LSI system')
```

Next, we define signal

```
# Signal X in range [-1,1]
X = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
```

The, define System

```
# Transformation T 
T = lambda x: np.sin(x)
```

Now lets see everything we defined in action

```
a = 1
b = 1
tau = 2*np.pi
# Check Linearity
check_linearity(T, X, a, b);
# Check Shift Invariance
check_shift_invariance(T, X, tau);
# Check LSI or not
check_LSI(T, X, a, b, tau);
```

You can easily define other systems like,

```
T = lambda x: x
T = lambda x:  np.sin(x) + np.cos(x)
T = lambda x: x**2 + x + 2
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

@Ragnar provided a very nice mathematical solution, but I want to post a short one.

If your function is given by the values which are equispaced, then

```
print(all(abs(x) < 0.001 for x in np.diff(function, n=2)))
```

returns `True` if the function is linear and `False` otherwise.

The idea is that each time, the function is incremented by the same value (here I use that `X` is equispaced). Therefore, taking the difference of consecutive numbers should return the array with all identical entries. Taking the difference of the consecutive numbers again returns all zeros if the function is linear.